# Opening links externally

Tags: cordova

What is the correct way to open some url's in safari using Cordova 2.5.0?

i tried:

```
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
```

Though, it didn't work. And also my first load is an external document.

Answer (score 0):

To open a web page in external browser, use `navigator.app.loadUrl('http://www.google.com', { openExternal:true } );`

Probably, now api changed to `window.open("http://www.google.com", "_system");` didn't tested for real